# How to add notification in the sidebar of the administration panel when a Custom post type is created?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, notifications

I have added a custom post type called: "Partners", what I want is that when a new one is created, a notification appears in the sidebar of Wordpress.

For example:

[image]

regards!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

It is shockingly simple: you have to dyamically set the admin page title, adding a specific markup:

```
<span class='awaiting-mod count-3'>
  <span class='pending-count'>3</span>
</span>
```

So for example if you want to show the number of custom posts you have to do something like this when declaring the options page:

```php
$notif_count = wp_count_posts('my_post_type'); //insert your post type
add_menu_page("My Page Title", 
              "My Page Title <span class='awaiting-mod count-$notif_count'><span class='pending-count'>$notif_count</span></span>", 
              'administrator',
              'my_slug', 
              'my_handler_function'
);
```

Notice the php variable `$notif_count` inside the second parameter of `add_menu_page`.